# An offer for project with source code

Tags: ms-project

A company is offering me project with source code the offer is like following(generic):

Grab your Last Chance to Buy "product name" with Source code for "limited" licenses
at just $.

I am curious about that what is the benefit of source code with limited licenses?

Comment: This question is about the relative merits of software licensing terms, and doesn't appear to directly relate to the field of project management.

Answer (score 3):

The source code and the usage licenses are two different things.

Having the [source code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code) helps when the original manufacturer for some reason goes away. You can fix bugs or add features even decades after you purchased the product. Also you could audit the code for security issues and such.

Some companies also put the source-code in [Escrow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escrow) to make sure that you can use and update the software, for example when the original manufacturer goes bankrupt.

[Licenses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_license) are usage agreements, it describes how you are allowed to use the product.
Even if you alter the source-code you still need to follow the license agreement. For example you cannot re-brand it and re-sell it.

Comment: what about this? http://www.fedena.com/oem_partner